# An efficient way to convert ByteData in Dart to unsigned char* in C++?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I'm doing it in this way:

```
Pointer<Uint8> _byteDataToPointer(ByteData byteData) {
  final uint8List = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  final length = uint8List.lengthInBytes;
  final result = allocate<Uint8>(count: length);

  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    result[i] = uint8List[i];
  }

  return result;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way like [JNIEnv::GetByteArrayRegion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_PrimitiveType_ArrayRegion_routines) in JNI?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always going to involve a copy, so is there something more efficient than your for loop? Maybe.

After allocating your `Uint8Pointer` use `asTypedList` to convert it to a `Uint8List`. Now you have access to its copy primitive like `setAll` and `setRange` to copy from the source to the destination.

What's the original source of the `ByteData`? If you knew the size in advance, could you allocate the Uint8Pointer first, convert to typed data and then read directly into that?

Comment: Thank you~! `asTypedList` is what I need!

Comment: and the original source of the `ByteData` is `rootBundle.load`, I don't find a way to read directly into my Uint8List